# I am new to mongoDB need a query to delete the collections

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections.

1.Equipment

```
    db.getCollection("Equipment").find({ 
    $and: [
        { $where: 'this._id.length <= 7' },
        { "model": "A505"}
    ]})


{
    "_id" : "1234567",
    "locationId" : "DATALOAD",
    "model" : "A505",
    "subscriberId" : "",
    "status" : "Stock",
    "headendNumber" : "4"
}

{
    "_id" : "P13050I",
    "locationId" : "1423110302801",
    "model" : "A505",
    "subscriberId" : "37",
    "status" : "Stock",
    "headendNumber" : "4"
}
```

I will get more than 100 documents (rows) Equipment collection.

2.Subscriber

```
db.getCollection('Subscriber').find({})

{
    "_id" : "5622351",
    "equipment" : [ 
        "0018015094E6", 
        "1234567", 
        "ADFB70878422", 
        "M10610TCB052", 
        "MA1113FHQ151"
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "490001508063",
    "equipment" : [ 
        "17616644510288", 
        "P13050I", 
        "M91416EA4251", 
        "128552270280560"
    ]
}
```

In the Subscriber collection, I need to remove (get all the id from Equipment collection loop it) only the matches equipment field.
Forex from the above result, I need to remove only  "1234567", and "P13050I"

Expected output.

```
db.getCollection('Subscriber').find({})

{
    "_id" : "5622351",
    "equipment" : [ 
        "0018015094E6", 

        "ADFB70878422", 
        "M10610TCB052", 
        "MA1113FHQ151"
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : "490001508063",
    "equipment" : [ 
        "17616644510288", 

        "M91416EA4251", 
        "128552270280560"
    ]
}
```

Please help me, anyone.

Comment: what is your DB version ?

Comment: my current version is 3.6.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to update records.

Let's find records which need to deleted and store them in array

```
var equipments = [];

db.getCollection("Equipment").find({ $and: [
    { $where: 'this._id.length <= 7' },
    { "model": "A505"}
]}).forEach(function(item) => {
    equipments.push(item._id)
})
```

Now, iterate over records of the second collection and update if required.

```
db.getCollection('Subscriber').find({}).forEach(function(document) => {
    var filtered = document.equiment.filter(id => equipments.indexOf(id) < 0);

    if(filtered.length < document.equipment.length){
        db.getCollection('Subscriber').update({"_id": document.id }, { $set: {'equipment': filtered}})
    }
})
```

`.filter(id => equipments.indexOf(id) < 0)` will keep entries which is not present in initially populated array `equipments` and it will persist if there is any change.